# Can I adjust a cell value in excel based on the input from another cell?

Tags: excel

I am creating an inventory management system for our local foodbank and would like to keep a running inventory of the food in our inventory.  I can input the initial quantity, but would like the cell to adjust automatically (up or down) based on user inputs.

As an example:
Item    Qty
Soup    200
Rice    300

If we use up 100 cans of soup and 50 bags of rice, I would like the new inventory to now show:
Item    Qty
Soup    100
Rice    250

I don't want to create a separate columns which updates the qty field each time I add or remove items.
Is this possible?

Comment: very easy with VBA.  Are you Okay with VBA //

Comment: This is pretty basic Excel functionality. Can you show us how your Excel page currently looks like? And how are you planning to do input? Just adding a cell at the end or do you want to use another method?

Comment: I can muddle through some VBA.  I have a little programming experience with R, Fortran and currently working on Python.  I want to have the quantity column to adjust each month as we add content or give away in the food bags.  Ideally, I will set up a form that allows us to choose what food to include in the bags and identify the quantity.  It would then subtract that amount from the quantity line.  I don't want to create a separate column with amount used each time I adjust.  Seems like this should be easy, but it's not apparent to me.

Comment: You can do this without VBA it, as mentioned by @Dominique the functionality is built into Excel with no need for programming. I think you should give it a try as I described below and then ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would accomplish this:

1. In a separate sheet create a list of the "Items"
2. Create a drop-down list to pick the items from the list (google how to do it)
3. You can subtract the items used by using a SUMIFS formula.

I've created a simple google sheet to show how it could be done...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bFwXcta-B3OtNMTi3arzLMlQJbjAU-w0wmkj6H3jiKM/edit?usp=sharing